# plots with twisted data

Tags: linux

question has been delted sorry for inconvenience caused to anyone referiing

Comment: Do you mean to have 2 calls to `geom_point` that both filter for `Categories == "Diffs"`? Do you mean one to filter for "Diffs" and one for "rare"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a possible solution using a couple of bits of dummy aesthetics.

I called `geom_boxplot` on a subset of the data to exclude "Diff" and "rare". I gave this a dummy color aesthetic in order to get a legend for the boxplot.

Then I called `geom_point` on a subset where the data is only "Diff" or "rare". `ggplot` expects long shaped data, so rather than filtering for values and calling `geom_point` twice, you want to instead call `geom_point` once and use an aesthetic to have two different shapes.

The next step was controlling labels to match what you're after and hide the dummies. Adding `guide = guide_legend(order = 1)` or `order = 2` sets the order of the legends, so that the one for Method A comes before the one for Method B.

One drawback is that there are two Method B legends, one for color and one for shape. That's because they have two different sets of levels. A workaround might be possible with `interaction(section, Categories)` instead.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

df <- structure(
    list(Categories = c("Aaas", "Aaas", "Aaas", "Aaas", "Bbbs", "Bbbs", "Bbbs", "Bbbs", "Cccs", "Cccs", "Cccs", "Cccs", "Diffs", "Diffs", "Diffs", "Diffs", "rare", "rare", "rare", "rare"), 
             section = c("red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "red", "blue", "green", "yellow"),
             range = c("top1K", "top2K", "top3K", "top4K", "top1K", "top2K", "top3K", "top4K", "top1K", "top2K", "top3K", "top4K", "top1K", "top2K", "top3K", "top4K", "top1K", "top2K", "top3K", "top4K"),
             values = c(20L, 32L, 42L, 32L, 21L, 12L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 13L, 43L, 21L, 2L, 10L, 13L, 11L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 9L)), 
    class = "data.frame", 
    row.names = c(NA, -20L), 
    spec = structure(list(cols = structure(list(dummy = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", "collector")), Categories = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", "collector")), section = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", "collector")), range = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", "collector")), values = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", "collector"))), 
                                                                                 .Names = c("dummy", "Categories", "section", "range", "values")), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", "collector"))), .Names = c("cols", "default"), class = "col_spec"), .Names = c("Categories", "section", "range", "values"))


ggplot(df, aes(x = range, y = values)) +
    geom_boxplot(aes(fill = "Type A"), data = df[!df$Categories %in% "Diffs" & !df$Categories %like% "rare", ]) +
    geom_jitter(data = df[!df$Categories %in% "Diffs" & !df$Categories %like% "rare", ]) +
    geom_point(aes(color = Categories, shape = section), data = df[df$Categories %in% "Diffs" | df$Categories %like% "rare", ]) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = "white", guide = guide_legend(order = 1)) +
    scale_color_discrete(guide = guide_legend(order = 2), labels = c("Type B", "Type C")) +
    labs(fill = "Method A", color = "Method B", shape = "Method B")
```

[image]

Created on 2018-04-22 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: @Ary okay, editing my answer now. I think I've got it

Comment: Okay, now you're losing me! In that case, you'd have shape mapped to section in one place and Categories in another---is that what you want? The legends are going to get crowded in that case.

Comment: Got it. The problem is that you can't have 2 different legends for shape. Even if two different geoms are mapping to shape, they'll both end up in the same legend.